# Prove $\frac{\left(\Gamma(1 + 1/p)\right)^n}{\Gamma(1 + n/p)}\to 1$ for $p =\frac{\ln n}{\ln\frac n {n-2}}$

Tags: limits, special-functions

As the title says, I wish to prove the limit (as $n\to \infty$)
$$\frac{\left(\Gamma(1 + 1/p)\right)^n}{\Gamma(1 + n/p)}\to 1\qquad \text{ for } p =\frac{\ln n}{\ln\frac n {n-2}}$$
Any hints?

The expression is the volume of the p-ball $B_p(1/2)=\{x:\|x\|_p≤1/2\}$
. The parameter $p$ is chosen so that $B_p(1/2)$ is tangent to the orthoschemes of $[−1/2,1/2]^n$. All p-ball volumes converge to $0$ for fixed $p$. The orthoscheme has volume $1/n!$ by the determinant simplex formula. I expect the volume of the tangent ball to converge to $1$ and numerically it does...

The idea is that a p-ball volume converges to $0$, as well as the orthoschemes of the hypercube, but if $p$ grows appropriately as the dimensions grow, then clearly that is not the case. (For instance, $[-1/2,1/2]^n$ is just $\{x : \|x\|_\infty \leq 1/2\}$). To find such a $p$, one way is to guess the p-ball will be tangent to the orthoschemes.

For the p-ball volume formula see the note [1].
[1] Xianfu Wang, Volumes of Generalized Unit Balls, [DOI:10.2307/30044198](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/30044198)

Comment: Maybe you could add some context?

Comment: The expression is the volume of the p-ball $B_p(1/2) = \{x : \|x\|_p \leq 1/2\}$. The parameter $p$ is chosen so that $B_p(1/2)$ is orthonormal to the orthoschemes of $[-1/2, 1/2]^n$. All p-ball volumes converge to $0$ for fixed $p$. The orthoscheme has volume $1/n!$ by the determinant simplex formula. I expect the volume of the tangent ball to converge to $1$ and numerically it does...

Comment: I would try the integral definition of the Gamma function, but not sure. What are your thoughts?

Comment: That's good advice. I was trying the Stirling formula but I don't think I was doing it right. I'll try the integral definition and see if there's a trick.

Comment: TheAlertGerbil, copy your first comment into the body of the question. It might lead to reopening of the question. I'll vote for reopening at least

Comment: Is p the p-adic norm here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following manner:
First, I prove that $n/p\to 0$. This comes from:
$$n/p = \frac{n\log(\frac n{n-2})}{\log(n)} \to \frac 2 \infty = 0$$
Then the denominator is dealt with, as $\Gamma$ is continuous. As for the numerator, the fact that $n/p\to 0$ along with the fact that $\Gamma$ is analytic around $1$ gives me $\left(\Gamma(1 + 1/p)\right)^n \to 1$ by using the log expansion,

$$n\ln\Gamma(1 + 1/p) = -\gamma n/p + O(n/p^2) \to 0$$
In fact this is also true for p-balls with $p = n^{1 + \epsilon}$.